# Define the window location of the output of shell command

Tags: window, shell-command

I use  `M-!` to run the command `shell-command`. The output will open the buffer in a new window at the bottom. Can I configure it to appear on the right?

Comment: See the variables `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html

Comment: This must be a duplicate. Seems like there are multiple questions asking how to position the window that displays a buffer. If so, it would be helpful if someone consolidated them and we closed all but one.

Answer (score 0):

Packages that help you to customize window location settings include [Shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) (my recommendation) and [Popwin](https://github.com/m2ym/popwin-el)

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer to help the OP? For example, what would be the exact shackle rules to get what the OP wants?